# Can't access an object's context in window.resize()

Tags: javascript

I can handle context this way in other methods, and I'm not sure what is different about .resize(), or why I'm unable to pass in a context.

```
 D4.prototype.resize = function() {
    var that = this;
    that.containerBound = that.getBound(that.containerId);
    // that is referring to the DomWindow and not D4

  };

  $(window).resize(D4.prototype.resize);
```

Comment: You want it to refer to the constructor function (`D4`)?

Comment: I'd like to be able to define in the object what happens to the object when the window resizes.

Comment: do you want to call the prototype function? or the function of it's instance?

Comment: hmm, aren't those the same things, or is that what I'm misunderstanding? If I call the prototype function can't I access all of the instance values?  In this case I'd like to be able to recalculate the X and Y domain ranges in a D3 graph, so I need the instance values.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/QJLTa/4/):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    D4.prototype.resize('prototype:');
    myD4.resize('instance:')
});
```

Comment: Both these snippets make `this` refer to dom window inside the method, which wasn't what the op wants

Comment: @Esailija seems like i misunderstood the question. Now updating.